# Где можно хранить данные во время работы приложения

Tags: android, android-fragment

Где можно хранить данные во время работы приложения.То есть данные данные находятся в 1 фрагменте. Я открываю второй фрагмент, после возвращаюсь к первому фрагменту и чтоб вектор остался с теми же значениями.

```
 Vector <Address> VectorAddress;


public class Address
{
    String name;
    double lon;
    double lan;
    Levels level; //Пользовательский класс

    ...get,set методы
}
```

Comment: Сделайте его public static и обращайтесь откуда угодно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил с помощью Application.

В манифесте надо еще указать область видимости `android:name="com.example.LocationAddress"`

Для ввода значения использую

```
locationAddress = (LocationAddress)getActivity().getApplication();
locationAddress.setNazalo_marhruta_adress(addressVector.get(0));
```

Аналогично и для получения, использую get-методы.

```
public class LocationAddress extends Application {
    public  ArrayList<Address> nazalo_marhruta_masssiv;
    public  ArrayList <Address> ceredina_marhruta_massiv;
    public  ArrayList <Address> konez_marhruta_massiv;

    public Address nazalo_marhruta_adress;
    public Address ceredina_marhruta_adress;
    public Address konez_marhruta_adress;

    public ArrayList<Address> getNazalo_marhruta_masssiv() {
        return nazalo_marhruta_masssiv;
    }

    public void setNazalo_marhruta_masssiv(ArrayList<Address> nazalo_marhruta_masssiv) {
        this.nazalo_marhruta_masssiv = nazalo_marhruta_masssiv;
    }

    public ArrayList<Address> getCeredina_marhruta_massiv() {
        return ceredina_marhruta_massiv;
    }

    public void setCeredina_marhruta_massiv(ArrayList<Address> ceredina_marhruta_massiv) {
        this.ceredina_marhruta_massiv = ceredina_marhruta_massiv;
    }

    public ArrayList<Address> getKonez_marhruta_massiv() {
        return konez_marhruta_massiv;
    }

    public void setKonez_marhruta_massiv(ArrayList<Address> konez_marhruta_massiv) {
        this.konez_marhruta_massiv = konez_marhruta_massiv;
    }

    public Address getNazalo_marhruta_adress() {
        return nazalo_marhruta_adress;
    }

    public void setNazalo_marhruta_adress(Address nazalo_marhruta_adress) {
        this.nazalo_marhruta_adress = nazalo_marhruta_adress;
    }

    public Address getCeredina_marhruta_adress() {
        return ceredina_marhruta_adress;
    }

    public void setCeredina_marhruta_adress(Address ceredina_marhruta_adress) {
        this.ceredina_marhruta_adress = ceredina_marhruta_adress;
    }

    public Address getKonez_marhruta_adress() {
        return konez_marhruta_adress;
    }

    public void setKonez_marhruta_adress(Address konez_marhruta_adress) {
        this.konez_marhruta_adress = konez_marhruta_adress;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Если данные вычислимые и/или нужны только на время работы приложения, то можно создать для их хранения [singleton класс](https://habrahabr.ru/post/27108/) такого вида:

```
public class MyStorage {

    private List<Address> _addresses;

    // единственный экземпляр класса
    private static MyStorage _instance = new MyStorage();

    private MyStorage(){}

    public static MyStorage getInstance(){ return _instance; }

    /*
    Необходимые методы для доступа к данным или дополнительная логика
    */
}
```

Если же данные нужно хранить "по-настоящему", стоит посмотреть в сторону хранения в базе данных.

Comment: Спасибо разобрался. Данные нужны только во время программы. То есть мне не нужно  хранить их после выхода из приложения. Да и выйдет слишком много запросов к базе данных